# Does "Bests" mean "Best regards" in emails?

Tags: email, valediction

One of my colleagues (not a native English speaker) always ends his emails like this:

> Bests 
> Mike

I guess he means ***Best regards*** with ***Bests***. Could someone help explain?

Comment: I've never seen anyone end a letter or email with that before. It might just be a personal quirk unique to your colleague?

Comment: googled a bit more. could it possibly mean "Best regards & best wishes", 2 best's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where Mike is from.  Perhaps there is a similar expression in his native language which he has tried to replicate in English.  Or perhaps he has a personal reason for using this phrase.

However without that additional context, this is not *technically* a proper way to end an email.  Here are some alternatives which are typical and similar (there are many more):

- Best
- Best Regards
- Best Wishes
- All the Best

Comment: i speak the same native lang as he. we don't have such expression. thanks for the explanation. at least i got to know it's not commonly used english.